# Add a column to a table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

how to add a column to my table `Users`.

because I ran the migration, I have to do something like:

```
rails generate migration AddShowmsgColumnToUsers show_msg:boolean
```

and then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

but I'm not sure about "`AddShowmsgColumnToUsers`". how can I know how it suppose to be? why not: `AddShow_msgColumnToUsers`? if the problem was pluralization and singularization, I can run the `rails console` and check that, but how can I know about the uppercase letter: ShowMsg/Show_msg/Show_Msg/Showmsg? is there a command that helps me to check it?

Comment: Why is your form is in 'get' method? and how is parameter formed can you post it

Comment: sorry, I'm updating my topic.

Comment: can you explain your second question again please?

Comment: When you submitting the form a parameter is generated and passed to action that you specified in the form' action just simply add this `puts params` in first line of your update action check the console, does the show_msg attribute is present and has the correct value?

Comment: what does the `action` should be? I tried to make it blank but it redirect me to the login page and wants me to sign in again. <form name="input" action="" method="post"> thank you very much!

Comment: I edit this message, delete my second question and post it in a new topic. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question, it doesn't matter, as long as the table name is correct - Rails uses the arguments you specify for the columns rather than the name of the migration.

Also, you should only really be asking one question at a time... ;-)

Comment: It's cool. :) It just confuses things if you have multiple answers for different parts of your questions. Removing the second part, and putting it in a new question is probably a good idea, you can always link back to this question if you want to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a migration to add an column, you should use either camelcase or underscores. Besides you dont have to put "Column"  inside your migration generator, with Add...To... the migration already knows you are adding a column.

So either:

```
rails generate migration AddShowMsgToUsers show_msg:boolean
```

or:

```
rails generate migration add_show_msg_to_users show_msg:boolean
```

Is the way to go. The migration-generator will result in the following migration:

```
class AddShowMsgToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :show_msg, :boolean
  end
end
```

Of course you could also do it all manually, but the whole point of generators is that you don't need to write everything yourself.